# Is temporary object originally const?

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, temporary-objects

Is this code UB?

```
struct A
{
 void nonconst() {}
};

const A& a = A{};
const_cast<A&>(a).nonconst();
```

In other words, is the (temporary) object originally `const`? I've looked through the standard but cannot find an answer so would appreciate quotations to relevant sections.

***Edit:*** for those saying `A{}` is not `const`, then can you do `A{}.nonconst()` ?

Comment: The temporary itself that is created by `A{}` is not const.  You are simply creating a const reference to it, and then you are casting away that const-ness then accessing the temporary. That does not change the const-ness of the temporary itself. It is not UB to cast away const-ness from a pointer/reference if you are sure the object being pointed/referenced is not actually const. It WOULD be UB if the object were actually const, eg `const A a; const A &ref = a; const_cast<A&>(ref).nonconst();`

Comment: You can even bind it to `A&&`.

Comment: I don't think it is really called temporary, as const reference prolongs lifetime in this case.

Comment: In response to your edit, [yes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/215f88184c350c75)

Comment: @AlexanderGutenev How do you call it?

Comment: @Jarod42 Temporaries were never inherently immutable in C++; historically you could do `string() = "hello"` or `vector<int>().push_back(1)`. (And there was no rvalue reference at that time.)

Comment: @RemyLebeau _The temporary itself that is created by `A{}` is not const._ In C++17, `A{}` does not even create a temporary object.

Comment: @AlexanderGutenev "_I don't think it is really called temporary_" How do you call it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The initialization of the reference `a` is given by [[dcl.init.ref]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.3) (bold mine):

> Otherwise, if the initializer expression
>
> - is an rvalue (but not a bit-field)[...]
>
> then the value of the initializer expression in the first case and the result of the conversion in the second case is called the converted initializer.
>   **If the converted initializer is a prvalue, its type T4 is adjusted to type “cv1 T4” ([conv.qual])** and the temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied.

So it means that the type prvalue expression that initialize the reference, `A{}`, is adjusted to `const A`.

Then [[conv.rval]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rval#1) states:

> A prvalue of type T can be converted to an xvalue of type T.
>   This conversion initializes a temporary object ([class.temporary]) of type T.

So the type of the temporary object, bound to the reference is the same as the adjusted `prvalue` type: `const A`.

So the code `const_cast<A&>(a).nonconst();` is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: _So the code const_cast<A&>(a).nonconst(); is undefined behavior_ I've thought UB is to modify a const object. Here there is no modification.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer True I supposed the code above was an illustration not the production code. So I did not considered the body of nonconst as meaningfull.

Answer (score 3):

The type of a temporary is whatever type you declared it with.

Unfortunately, as [Oliv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632316/oliv) points out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54335024/4342498) reference initialization rules transform the type to match the reference type so in this case `a` actually refers to a `const A`.  It is basically doing

```
using const_A = const A;
const A& a = const_A{};
```

---

Because you can actually create constant prvalues if you ever want to stop a overload set from accepting a constant prvalue you need to have

```
ret_type function_name(some_type const&&) = delete;
```

otherwise if you have

```
ret_type function_name(some_type const&)
```

in the overload set it then the constant prvalue would bind to that if you only deleted

```
ret_type function_name(some_type&&)
```

instead. You can see this working with

```
struct bar{};

void foo(bar const&) { std::cout << "void foo(bar const&)\n"; }
void foo(bar&&) =delete;

using c_bar = const bar;

int main()
{   
    foo(c_bar{});
}
```

Here, `void foo(bar const&)` gets called since `c_bar{}` is actually `const` instead of getting a deleted function error if you had used `foo(bar{});`.  Adding

```
void foo(bar const&&) = delete;
```

is needed to actually stop `foo(c_bar{});` from compiling.