# Why const_cast doesn't work with raw template function with Eigen?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

A MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;


void foo(const MatrixXf& m) {
  const_cast<MatrixXf& >(m).setZero();
}


template<typename T>
void bar(const Matrix<T, -1, -1>& m) {
  const_cast<Matrix<T, -1, -1>&>(m).setZero();
}


template<typename Derived>
void baz(const MatrixBase<Derived>& m) {
  const_cast<MatrixBase<Derived>& >(m).setZero();
}


int main() { 
  MatrixXf M = MatrixXf::Random(2, 6);
  cout << "Init:" << endl;
  cout << M << endl;

  foo(M.block(0, 0, 2, 2));
  cout << "After foo:" << endl;
  cout << M << endl;
  
  bar<float>(M.block(0, 2, 2, 2));
  cout << "After bar: " << endl; 
  cout << M << endl;

  baz(M.block(0, 4, 2, 2));
  cout << "After baz: " << endl; 
  cout << M << endl;
}
```

Output

```
Init:
  0.680375   0.566198   0.823295  -0.329554  -0.444451 -0.0452059
 -0.211234    0.59688  -0.604897   0.536459    0.10794   0.257742
After foo:
  0.680375   0.566198   0.823295  -0.329554  -0.444451 -0.0452059
 -0.211234    0.59688  -0.604897   0.536459    0.10794   0.257742
After bar: 
  0.680375   0.566198   0.823295  -0.329554  -0.444451 -0.0452059
 -0.211234    0.59688  -0.604897   0.536459    0.10794   0.257742
After baz: 
 0.680375  0.566198  0.823295 -0.329554         0         0
-0.211234   0.59688 -0.604897  0.536459         0         0
```

I read Eigen document [Writing Functions Taking Eigen Types as Parameters](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html). In the case we pass const reference to function, I was wondering why I cannot `const_cast` raw reference to achieve modifying data? In my example, why my `foo` and `bar` don't work? Is `const_cast` treat `MatrixBase<Derived>&` and `Matrix<T, -1, -1>&` diffierent?

Comment: You are not allowed to cast away const.  What should happen if you passed an actual const object to the function?

Comment: foo and bar do not match exactly the type which is passed to them. The result of block is an object which has a conversion operator to the target type, and that conversion operator performs a copy. The reference parameters in foo and bar are bound to a temporary object; you modify that object and it is discarded when the function returns. In baz, the argument type does match the parameter type exactly - no conversion operator is invoked and no temporaries are materialized. There the eigen expression template holds a reference to the original value and you modify that object directly.

Comment: @NathanOliver This `const_cast` method is mentioned in official document of Eigen in above link. The const reference using `const_cast` mainly play "output" role in function parameters. In the case of const "input" parameters, you are right, it shouldn't cast away.

Comment: If the `block` function returns by value then I believe the you may be obligated to consider them `const` objects. If it returns by value then `M.block(0, 2, 2, 2)` is a prvalue expression. So I think [temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) occurs. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334861/is-temporary-object-originally-const) it looks like the value has to be treated as a `const` object. If this is correct using the result of `const_cast` would be Undefined Behavior.